# Debian 8 Jessie, kernel panic on shutdown

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I have my Asus M5A99FX (with AMD FX6300 6-core processor and 16GB of memory) loaded with Debian Jessie and KDE. Everything seems to be working fine until I shut down the system. I click the shutdown command within KDE and seconds later the screen contains error statements ending with the statement kernel panic. I know this to be a kernel crash. I can logout which will return me to graphical login prompt where I can then go to a command prompt and Ctrl-Alt-Del and it will shut down correctly. It appears that if I do not let KDE shut the system down and do it manually it will work correctly. I am betting there is a bug in KDE that is causing this.

My question is how can I disable to graphical login so I have to login from a command prompt? I don't mind having to giving an init6 or init0 command from a command line.

Comment: That's strange. Have you reported the bug? Are you sure it isn't hardware related?

Comment: Not sure how to report a bug,but will if I can. The same computer ran Wheezy just fine. Maybe I'll have to revert back.

Comment: Debian-specific bugs are reported to bugs.debian.org.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your display manager - KDE uses KDM I believe. Update: On rereading I might not have been clear - your display manager KDM et el, is what gives one the login prompt to your X. Removing that should give you a command prompt - That's what you wanted, right?

To report a Debian bug, if you have the package 'reportbug' launch it from a terminal and follow the prompts.